# Is there an O(n log n) algorithm for 4D line simplification?

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, randomized-algorithms

The [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) for line simplification has worst-case $O(n^2)$ runtime. For suitably distributed random inputs, it has expected $O(n \log n)$ runtime complexity. In 2D, there are other algorithms with worst case $O(n \log n)$ runtime complexity, which compute exactly the same result as the Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm. Since these algorithms are based on a "path (convex) hull" datastructure, it is not obvious whether they can be generalized to 4D lines.

Is there a (randomized) algorithm which has (expected) $O(n \log n)$ runtime (independent of input) for the case of 4D lines? You may assume Euclidean distances and a global absolute tolerance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm that works with 4D case is described in the article *[Near-Linear Time Approximation Algorithms for Curve Simplification](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.3161&rep=rep1&type=pdf)* by four authors: *Pankaj K. Agarwal, Sariel Har-Peled, Nabil H. Mustafa, and Yusu Wang*.

> Given a polygonal curve $P$ in $\mathcal R^d$
>   and a parameter $\epsilon \ge 0$, an $\epsilon$-simplification of
>   $P$ with size at most $\mathcal \kappa_F(\epsilon/2, P)$
>   can be constructed in $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ time and $\mathcal O(n) $ space.

The algorithm does not depend on monotonicity properties. It covers the original line with disks and seeks the line traversal on the ordered set.

Sidenote:
There is a modification of Douglas-Peucker algorithm with the worst-case in $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ described in the paper *An O(n log n) Implementation of the Douglas-Peucker Algorithm for Line Simplification.* by *John Hershberger and Jack Snoeyink*: [improved DP line simplification](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs350/spring06/Lecture-Handouts/hershberger92speeding.pdf). Indeed it uses path hull.